# Diffrerent exceptions when creating files on external storage

Tags: java, android, file, permissions, android-external-storage

I am receiving different crashes when creating files on external storage in non appliation specific folder. This code works fine for most users, but failing for some. I am using approximately following code when creating files:

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return (Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state));
}

public File getTargetDirectory() {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File(root, "DIRECTORY");
    directory.mkdirs();
    return directory;
}

public static void createFile() {
    if (isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
        File file = new File(getTargetDirectory(), "filename.dat");
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        //other code...
    }
}
```

I have following permission in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am receiving different Exceptions (wrapped in `java.io.IOException`) when `createNewFile()` is executed:

```
libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
1   libcore.io.Posix.open   
2   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open    BlockGuardOs.java, line 110
3   java.io.File.createNewFile  File.java, line 941

libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1   libcore.io.Posix.open   
2   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open    BlockGuardOs.java, line 110
3   java.io.File.createNewFile
```

These exceptions happen on different Android devices running different OS versions. This folder is basically drop in folder where app is writing data for user to transfer to different devices. So user can copy this folder from his PC.

Could it be some kind of read only permission issue?

Comment: you don't set permission in manifest for reading and writing file

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, thanks for noticing it. Updated question. This happens only for some users. I have following permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.